# Avoid line break

Tags: html

I want to keep * in same line as question.

div inside first span is generated from code,cannot apply any css for that!

```
<div class="main">
  <span class="nobr"><div>
Where is ur pen?
</div>
<span class="ast">*</span>
  </span>
</div>

.nobr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.ast {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ByGVE/41/

The inner div(it can contain nested divs) is a dynamically generated code( html from backend-SharePoint list rich text field). I have to add an asterisk after the question.

Comment: Disregard - comment was made without seeing the fiddle.

Comment: @CmdrSharp The question is perfectly clear to me so that's kinda uncalled for?

Comment: @icecub I entirely agree. I either missed the fiddle, or it was just added - that kind of helped clear the question up a whole lot.

Comment: @CmdrSharp No problem. Anyway, since OP is telling us the `<div/>` is "generated" code, there isn't really a solution to the problem. A div is considdered "a block". So logically, any elements after it will appear on a new line. The best way to solve this would be to wrap the div and the span inside another div and use CSS floats to position them like OP wants. However, that can prove difficult with generated code and certainly can't be solved by us without knowing how this code is generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can put you text in span instead of div. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ByGVE/42/

```
<div class="main">
  <span class="nobr">
    <span>Where is ur pen?</span>
    <span class="ast">*</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Or if div is generated dynamically You can update following css

```
.nobr > div {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: OP clearly states that the `<div/>` is generated code. Meaning (s)he has no control over its contents or lacks the knowledge to manipulate the div at the level where it's generated. Therefor this solution won't work.

Comment: The inner div(it can contain nested divs) is a dynamically generated code( html from backend-SharePoint list rich text field). I have to add an asterisk after the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.nobr {
  
  display: inline;
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ast {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <span class="nobr">
    Where is ur pen?
  </span>
  <span class="ast">*</span>  
</div>
  </div>
```